# Ionic-2 app, let user enable/disable geo-location to app

Tags: angular, geolocation, ionic2

I build an Ionic app (by version 2 of Angular and Ionic).

In my app I have setting page.

I want to have a checkbox to let user enable/disable his geo-location for this app.

What is the best way to do that?